# How to trigger sudo's grace period for a given user via Puppet?

Tags: puppet, sudo

I am trying to deploy the [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) server via Puppet. The installation procedure [uses Bundle to install its dependencies](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Step-4-Dependencies-installation). When being installed interactively, `sudo` prompts user for password when Bundle needs to install some system-wide libraries. Installing Redmine as root is not recommended.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. The `puppet` is run from inside the LXC unprivileged container.

I used to have a walkaround that involved touching the appropriate `/var/lib/sudo` files prior the Bundle's installation. That is hacky, and ceased to work after recent sudo upgrade.

Is there any other way to do it? Or maybe sudo does allow granting grace period non-interactively and I simply missed it?

My `sudoers` file already contains the `Defaults     !tty_tickets` entry. I would prefer not to have it, but without this line I think there is even less hope for solution.

---

Here is my `forcesudo` resource:

```
define forcesudo ($user = $name, $notify = $notify) {
  file { "/etc/sudoers.d/fix-${user}": content => "${user} ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: ALL\n" }

  file { "/etc/sudoers.d/tty_tickets": content => "Defaults         !tty_tickets\n" }

  file { "/var/lib/sudo/${user}":
    ensure => directory,
    owner  => 'root',
    mode   => 700,
    group  => $user
  }

  file { "/var/lib/sudo/${user}/0":
    content => '',
    owner   => 'root',
    mode    => 0600,
    group   => $user
  }

  touch { "/var/lib/sudo/${user}":
    notify  => $notify,
    require => File["/var/lib/sudo/${user}"]
  }

  touch { "/var/lib/sudo/${user}/0":
    notify  => $notify,
    require => File["/var/lib/sudo/${user}"]
  }

}
```

And here is the `touch` resource:

```
define touch ($user = "root", $group = "root", $notify = $notify) {
  exec { "touch ${name}":
    command     => "/usr/bin/touch ${name}",
    user        => $user,
    group       => $group,
    notify      => $notify,
    refreshonly => true,
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

The problem can by bypassed by running the Bundle as root, although this is discouraged by the Bundle: `Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.`

This is how it is done by the https://github.com/johanek/johanek-redmine puppet module.

Since this is a workaround rather than fix, the question stands.

Comment: Please elaborate on how exactly you are doing this with puppet. Couldn't you just allow the user that installs redmine to run sudo without a password and tty just for the installation?

Comment: @fuero Here you are

Comment: @fuero From security point of view granting a `redmine` user right to run sudo without password forever is equivalent to running the web service as root. It is a bad practice. I am considering modifying the `sudoers` file just for the duration of the Bundle install, but I'd prefer to avoid it, as it creates illogical code dependency (what does the installation of redmine has to do with the sudoers file?)

Comment: Couldn't you just set the `user` attribute of the `exec` so that the command runs as `redmine`? No need for sudo at all. See https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, the `/etc/sudoers.d` is supported and I use it for the `/etc/sudoers.d/tty_tickets` file.

Comment: @PaulHaldane I do use it exactly like you have written. The problem is that the Bundle occasionally requires admin rights, which tries to get via `sudo`. And this is where the problem lays.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

Have you tried using a puppet module to accomplish this? There's at least [one](https://github.com/johanek/johanek-redmine) around that claims to be able to install redmine. It might be easier to just change it to fit your needs.

---

You didn't actually tell us how you launch the redmine installation via puppet.

Try adding this to your sudoers.d file:

```
Defaults:username !requiretty
```

There should be no need for the user launching the redmine installation to have a tty. There should be no password prompt either.

If sudo still prompts for a password, then there's something wrong in how the redmine installer invokes sudo.

As for your security concerns:

Best practice would be to use a package (RPM, DEB, etc.) anyway, even if you have to create it yourself.

Setting up puppet to remove temporary granted sudo privileges after installation is complete should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm not quite following this answer (sorry).  The OP says that (s)he's *not* permitting `NOPASSWD` sudo for the redmine user, and doesn't want to (and I think the concerns have some legitimacy).  So how do you think that setting `!requiretty` will help the redmine user perform the `sudo`?

Comment: The second line of OP's `forcesudo` resource *does* use `NOPASSWD`, so I was unsure what his real problem is. Which is why I want to see how OP actually installs redmine, not just how sudo is handled.

Comment: @fuero my Puppet manifest is just a sketch. I definitely don't want to have this `NOPASSWD` entry to prevail after the installation.

Comment: My word, points (well, +1) to you.  I'm not used to reading puppet resources, and you're right.  @AdamRyczkowski, could you clarify if this is working as shown, and you're simply having problems removing that permission-granting-file after the installation is all-but-complete?  Because I think this is exactly how things are *supposed* to work in `sudo`-world, these days.

Comment: @MadHatter ATM I have a strange (and possibly unrelated) problem with `redmine@redmine $ sudo su
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?`. I'll first troubleshoot it and then update the question.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski that is quite a departure from the original question; it might be better to accept an answer to this one, to put it to bed, and start a new question (though feel free to refer to this one in it, so people can see the historical development of the issue).  That's what I'd do, but of course you should do as you see fit!

Comment: Dear @MadHatter. I'll do it as soon as I am able to reproduce it, just give me a 20 minutes. Until then the original question (maybe temporarily) stands.

Comment: @fuero Thank you for the link. I'll try to merge it with my own module.

Comment: @fuero This repository works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @fuero Well, the module bypasses my problem by running the Bundle as root. And it runs the `Passenger AppRack: /opt/redmine` as `www-data` as opposed to the dedicated `redmine` user. I hope it is not a security issue